# Cordova sdk "deprecated" warning and error on drawable screen

Tags: android, cordova

I get the following output when and run cordova android with release version:

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (DEPRECATED)
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

...

F:\web\myapp\platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png: Error: The drawable "screen" in drawable-land-hdpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]
```

How do I fix the line that says DEPRCATED? I have installed SDK Platform package Android 9.0 (Pie) via Android Studio (Tools->SDK Manager) but that doesn't remove the DEPRECATED warning.

Also I have 14 errors relating to drawable "screen" and I'm not quite sure what to do with them.

Please help. Thank you in anticipation ))

Edited to add config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.mypp.app" version="1.3.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.31">
    <name>Myapp</name>
    <description>
        MyApp's description.
    </description>
    <author email="myapp@gmail.com" href="http://www.myapp.com">
        Myapp Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <icon src="www/img/icon.png" />
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all remove the following tag

```
<icon src="www/img/icon.png" />`
```

Then you will have to provide icons for all default densities(hdpi, ldpi, mdpi , xhdpi, xxhdpi, xxxhdpi) like below

```
 <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
 <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
 <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
 <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
 <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
 <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
```

If you don't have enough icons you can specify one icon for all the densities but according to the android specification you should provide separate icons.

Similarly, for splashscreens you can add the following

```
<splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-ldpi-splash.png" />
<splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-ldpi-splash.png" />
<splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-hdpi-splash.png" />
<splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-hdpi-splash.png" />
<splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-xhdpi-splash.png" />
<splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-xhdpi-splash.png" />
<splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-ldpi-splash.png" />
<splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-ldpi-splash.png" />
<splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-hdpi-splash.png" />
<splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-hdpi-splash.png" />
<splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-xhdpi-splash.png" />
<splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-xhdpi-splash.png" />
```

Comment: I'm not using screen.png. I have no idea how it came about as an error.

Comment: Can you share your config.xml ?

Comment: Sure. I have edited my main post to add config.xml as it's loo long to post in the comment.

Comment: Updated the answer. Let me know if its working or not. If working then accept the answer/upvote it.

Comment: Tried. It says "Source path does not exist: resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png".

Comment: I did not have any of those lines and cordova ran without those errors before. I only got the errors when I updated Android Studio to 3.5.1 (as well as SDK platforms which cordova requires) recently.

Comment: You will have to provide an icon /drawable-hdpi-icon.png or any icon like icon.png